# d3 remove and exit are not removing items properly in a stacked bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart that can be updated and filtered using a dropdown menu. When the chart first renders I don't have issues but when I uncheck an option, the rect does not get removed.

I checked the array after the removal and it does get removed from the array. The issue here is that the `rect` gets shifted to the far left. The x-axis does get updated and the text associated with that objects gets removed.

My feeling is that I have a problem with the selection, but I am confused because I have `rect` and `g` that represents the series for each object. I'm not sure if I am selecting the right object when I am removing elements.

My code: [Stacked bar chart with filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCr55cGqZN9U4858?preview)

Here is how the chart looks like after removing one item:

[image]

As you can see the `rect` is still there, but shifted to the left.

I have included the important part of my code. Any feedback even about how to make my code work on Plunker is appreciated

```js
d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function() {
  var paragraphID = d3.select(this).attr("id");
  paragraphID = String(paragraphID);

  if (this.checked) {
    if (paragraphID === 'A') {
      data.push({
        production_company: "A",
        Pass: 50,
        Fail: 65,
        total: 11
      });
    }
  } else {
    data = data.filter(d => d.production_company !== paragraphID);
  }

  xScale_production.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.production_company;
  }));
  
  yScale_production.domain([0, d3.max(series_production, d => d3.max(d, d => d[1]))]);

  var group = svg_stack_production.selectAll("g").data(series_production);
  var mbars = group.selectAll("rect").data(d => d);

  mbars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", d => yScale_production(d[1]))
    .attr("width", xScale_production.bandwidth())
    .merge(mbars)
    .attr("x", (d, i) => xScale_production(d.data.production_company))
    .attr("y", d => yScale_production(d[1]))
    .attr("width", xScale_production.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => yScale_production(d[0]) - yScale_production(d[1]));

  group.selectAll("g")
    .exit()
    .remove();

  mbars.selectAll("rect").exit().remove()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, there were two issues here. First, I needed to clone the original data and then apply the filtering on it as @Michael Rovinsky suggested.
Second, `series_production` needed to be updated after filtering the data.

here is the link for the working code.

[Working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCr55cGqZN9U4858?preview)

Answer (score 0):

No need to select elements before calling exit, they are already in selection. Just call:

```
group.exit().remove();

mbars.exit().remove();
```

instead of:

```
group.selectAll("g").exit().remove();

mbars.selectAll("rect").exit().remove();
```

Comment: That doen't solve the issue, but it allowed me to understand that definitely it's a selection problem because when I applied your suggestion the axis was removed. I have now added a class to `group` to ensure it doesn't select other `g` elements

Comment: If your problem persists, please provide a working snippet or fiddle

Comment: The Plunker link is working now. I changed the d3 version.

Comment: I see the problem. You load the data, build x scale and axis on it, then mutate the data on checkbox change... What you need to do is: save the loaded data and make it immutable, create a filtered copy of your data each time you check or uncheck, then redraw the whole chart with the filtered data

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I have incorporated your suggestion. I didn't know that I had to make the dataset immutable. However, my issue is not solved yet, the x-axis is the only element that gets updated. the bars still there.